# laravel join user meta table with another third table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a user table which as a user_meta table i want to get data from another third table based on user meta key and value

```
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $users = User::select('users.*')->with(['user_data'])->groupBy('users.id');
        $users = $users
            ->leftJoin('users_meta', 'users.id', '=', 'users_meta.users_id')
            ->leftJoin('districts', 'users_meta.users_id', '=', 'districts.user_id' and 'users_meta.key', '=', 'district_id' and 'users_meta.value', '=', 'districts.id')
            ->groupBy('users.id');
        $users->with(['districts', 'users_meta']);
```

DataTables warning: table id=ajax_data_table - Exception Message:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users_meta.users_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select `users`.* from `users` left join `users_meta` on `users`.`id` = `users_meta`.`users_id` left join `districts` on `users_meta`.`users_id` = `1` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null group by `users`.`id`, `users`.`id`) count_row_table)

Comment: "_Unknown column 'users_meta.users_id'_" We don't know your db structure, but shouldn't that column be `user_id`?

Comment: please share your users_meta migration

Comment: Its three tables Users (`id`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `user_type`, `group_id`, ...)
Users_meta (`id`, `user_id`, `type`, `key`, `value`)
Districts (`id`, `name`, `location_lat`, `location_lon`, `status`)

Uers blong to as districts which assagined as key = district_id and value = the id of district from districts table

Comment: Fixed by using                ->filterColumn('district', function ($user, $keyword) {
                    $user->whereHas("district", function ($q) use ($keyword) {
                        $q->whereRaw("districts.d_name like ?", ["%{$keyword}%"]);
                    });
                    return $user;
                })